# Begin Request slow for static content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, newrelic

I'm using New Relic to profile my ASP.NET MVC 5 (running on Azure) app. It's telling me that `BeginRequest` is taking a long time for static files, eg. PNG files, as shown in the image below.

My understanding is that `BeginRequest` is part of the managed code pipeline. However, I do not have `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` set in my Web.config, so I would have thought that the static content would be accessed by IIS directly without ASP.NET getting involved.

Does anyone know why `BeginRequest` is getting called here and why it would be so slow when it is called?

[image: Begin Request]

Comment: I found that the profiling tool I was using was causing the calls to DotNet and the slow times. Is it slow with the profiling tool removed completely?